# Extraer días intubación por covid según los dispositivos médicos utilizados para el paciente

Tags: python, pandas

Cordial saludo
Se necesita extraer los días que un paciente estuvo intubado en un servicio de salud para prevenir infecciones asociadas a la salud y ulceras por presión por estos dispositivos, **en PYTHON** lo siguiente lo debatimos con que si un paciente tiene CANULA_NASAL y cambia a TUBO_ENDOTRAQUEAL se cuente desde que inicia con tubo endotraqueal asta que aparece con el siguiente dispositivo que es CANULA_NASAL de este modo las cánulas nasales antes de la intubación no se tienen en cuenta para ejemplo el siguiente data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
data = io.StringIO("""
IDENTIFICACION    INSUMO     FECHA
2154821     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-01
2154821     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-03
2154821     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-13
2154821     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-20
2154821     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-25
2154821     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-29
949491914     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-02
949491914     CANULA_NASAL      2021-05-13
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     021-05-15
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-17
949491914     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-17
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     22021-05-25
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     22021-05-26
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     22021-05-27
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     22021-05-28
12345687     CANULA_NASAL     2021-04-25
12345687     CANULA_NASAL     2021-04-26
12345687     CANULA_NASAL     2021-04-27
12345687     CANULA_NASAL     2021-04-28
12345687     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-04-29
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-01
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-03
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-06
12345687     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-10
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
15134351     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-5
15134351     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-10
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")
df
```

Se obtiene los siguientes datos

```
    IDENTIFICACION  INSUMO  FECHA
0   2154821 CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-01
1   2154821 CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-03
2   2154821 TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL    2021-05-13
3   2154821 CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
4   2154821 CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-25
5   2154821 CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-29
6   949491914   TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL    2021-05-02
7   949491914   CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-13
8   949491914   CANULA_NASAL    021-05-15
9   949491914   CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-17
10  949491914   TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL    2021-05-17
11  949491914   CANULA_NASAL    22021-05-25
12  949491914   CANULA_NASAL    22021-05-26
13  949491914   CANULA_NASAL    22021-05-27
14  949491914   CANULA_NASAL    22021-05-28
15  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-04-25
16  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-04-26
17  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-04-27
18  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-04-28
19  12345687    TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL    2021-04-29
20  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-01
21  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-03
22  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-06
23  12345687    TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL    2021-05-10
24  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
25  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
26  12345687    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
27  15134351    CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-5
28  15134351    TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL    2021-05-10
```

se quiere extraer los siguientes datos con TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL como inicio descartando las CANULA_NASAL antes del TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL, de esta forma

```
IDENTIFICACION    INSUMO     FECHA
2154821     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-13
2154821     CANULA_NASAL     2021-05-20
949491914     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-02
949491914     CANULA_NASAL      2021-05-13
949491914     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-17
949491914     CANULA_NASAL     22021-05-25
12345687     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-04-29
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-01
12345687     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-10
12345687     CANULA_NASAL    2021-05-20
15134351     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-10
```

Para luego dejar la base de manera diagonal de cada TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL con su CANULA_NASAL si la tiene de lo contrario espacios vacios

```
IDENTIFICACION    INSUMO_1     FECHA_INSUMO_1    INSUMO_2     FECHA_INSUMO_2     Dia_intubacion
2154821     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-13     CANULA NASAL     2021-05-20         7
949491914     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-02     CANULA NASAL      2021-05-13         11
949491914     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-17     CANULA NASAL     22021-05-25         8
12345687     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-04-29     CANULA NASAL    2021-05-01         2
12345687     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-10     CANULA NASAL    2021-05-20         10
15134351     TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL     2021-05-10                                         null
```

De esta forma se sabe cuantos días estuvo un paciente hospitalizado con intubación mecánica, saben de que forma se puede realizar este proceso para no hacerlo manual?
**Gracias por su ayuda**

Comment: esto se puede interpretar como una tarea, no demuestras que has intentado resolver el problema, solo indicas lo que tienes que realizar y nada mas

Comment: Aquí no hay ningún problema con el código, simplemente no sabes que hacer.

Comment: Tienes y no tienes razón, No es una tarea, y ese es el 3% de todo el código que aun no sabemos como resolver ese pedazo, por eso lo planteamos así.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el metodo [`Dataframe.shift(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.DataFrame.shift) el cual compara la fila previa de tu dataframe, entonces, en terminos coloquiales:

> *Deme la fila donde INSUMO sea TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL o la fila siguiente donde el INSUMO de la fila previa sea TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL*

```
df = df[(df['INSUMO'] == 'TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL') | (df.shift(1)['INSUMO'] == 'TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL')].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

| IDENTIFICACION | INSUMO | FECHA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2154821 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-13 |
| 2154821 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-20 |
| 949491914 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-02 |
| 949491914 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-13 |
| 949491914 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-17 |
| 949491914 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-25 |
| 12345687 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-04-29 |
| 12345687 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-01 |
| 12345687 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-10 |
| 12345687 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-20 |
| 15134351 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-10 |

***Edit.***: Gracias a [*Christian*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian), me di cuenta que la respuesta estaba incompleta. Con los datos organizados que teniamos anteriormente, podemos continuar. Puedes usar [`pd.concat(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat) para concatenar dos dataframes, uno con informacion de `CANULA_NASAL` y otro con informacion de `TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL`.

Por ultimo, usando [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime) converimos a `datetime` las columnas `FECHA_1` y `FECHA_2`, para encontrar los días de intubación.

```
df_tubo = df[df['INSUMO'] == 'TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL']
df_tubo.rename(columns={'INSUMO': 'INSUMO_1', 'FECHA': 'FECHA_1'}, inplace=True) # Renombramos las columnas
df_tubo.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # Resteamos los indices

df_canula = df[df['INSUMO'] == 'CANULA_NASAL']
df_canula.rename(columns={'INSUMO': 'INSUMO_2', 'FECHA': 'FECHA_2'}, inplace=True) # Renombramos las columnas
df_canula.drop(columns=['IDENTIFICACION'], inplace=True) # Esta columna sobra, pues ya está en df_tubo
df_canula.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # Resteamos los indices

df = pd.concat([df_tubo, df_canula], axis=1)

df['Dia_intubacion'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_1']) - pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA_2'])).dt.days
print(df)
```

Output:

| IDENTIFICACION | INSUMO_1 | FECHA_1 | INSUMO_2 | FECHA_2 | Dia_intubacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2154821 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-13 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-20 | 7.0 |
| 949491914 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-02 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-13 | 11.0 |
| 949491914 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-17 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-25 | 8.0 |
| 12345687 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-04-29 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-01 | 2.0 |
| 12345687 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-10 | CANULA_NASAL | 2021-05-20 | 10.0 |
| 15134351 | TUBO_OROTRAQUEAL | 2021-05-10 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Comment: esto solo responde parcialmente la pregunta

Comment: Tienes razón... actualizaré la respuesta

Comment: gracias por la ayuda compadre

Comment: @seguridaddelpaciente si esta respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, no olvidés marcarla como correcta ✓. Eso ayuda a que otras personas encuentren más rápido la respuesta en el sitio, y me ayuda a crecer también :)